# Map with repeated argument clojure

Tags: clojure

Consider the following function as an example:

```
(defn f [x y] (+ x y))
```

I want to use this function to add 2 to each element of a vector:

```
[1 2 6 3 6]
```

I can use map:

```
(map f [1 2 6 3 6] [2 2 2 2 2])
```

But it seems a little ugly creating the second vector where every element is exactly the same.

So I thought using a closure was a better approach:

```
(map (fn g [x] (f x 2)) [1 2 6 3 6])
```

So my question is:

In clojure, what is the best way to use map when some arguments are not changing?

Comment: Use `mapv` instead of `map`, and you'll get another vector. `map`'s laziness doesn't buy you anything here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1**: use [repeat](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/repeat).

`(repeat 2)` gives you a lazy sequence of infinite `2`s

In your case,

```
(map f [1 2 6 3 6] [2 2 2 2 2])
```

should be converted into

```
(map f [1 2 6 3 6] (repeat 2))
```

**Approach 2**: use anonymous function

```
(map #(f % 2) [1 2 6 3 6])
```

Comment: Thanks, I like approach 1 because it uses my function f whereas approach 2 does not.

Comment: You can also use `(map #(f % 2) [1 2 6 3 6])` to use your function `f`.

Comment: Great! Are there any good reasons to choose Approach 1 versus 2?

Comment: They're two different kinds of thoughts, depending on what kind of function `f` is. I'd choose the second one in this case.

Comment: I'd say, if performance doesn't matter, use whichever option seems easier to understand (including `partial`, as mishadoff suggested).  If performance does matter, benchmark the options (using Criterium).  Sometimes the fastest method isn't what you'd expect.

Answer (score 4):

Just apply `partial` function

```
(map (partial + 2) [1 2 6 3 6]) => (3 4 8 5 8)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't use my existing function f. How would I use partial with my function f?

Comment: @user2179977 just replace `+` with `f`

Comment: In the example I gave, it doesn't matter in what order the arguments are passed to f, since it is just adding them. What if the ordering is important, for example `(defn f [x y] (x - y))`? If I provide one argument to `partial`, how does it know if it is `x` or `y`?

Comment: What if I want to give it the second and map over the first?

Comment: anonymous function is your friend `#(- x %)`